# How to loop over a list of variables in a dataframe, and for each variable apply a filter and get a weighted frequency table?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following example survey dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2),
                 age = c(15, 40, 97, 25, 99, 65, 20, 99, 39, 48), 
                 nationality= c(1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 97, 2, 2, 2, 99),
                 employment = c(2, 1, 99, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 income = c(-1, 2500, 999997, 10000, 65000, 999998, 999999, 15000, -1, -1),
                 weight = c(100, 20, 400, 300, 50, 50, 80, 250, 100, 100))
```

The following list contains selected variables that I want to use in a for loop:
`list <- list(age = df$age, employment = df$employment, income = df$income)`

I want to loop over the list of selected variables in the dataframe, and for each variable in the list apply a filter (condition) and get a weighted frequency table from the filtered data. In pseudocode this is what I want to do:

```
for i in list {
       filter(i >= 1 & i <= max(i)-2 %>%
       weighted frequency of var i based on 'weight' 
        }
```

I have tried many ways to do this in R but I still can’t figure out how. The last time I used this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(expss)
for (i in list){
     filter(i > 1 & i < max(i))-2 %>%
     fre(i, weight = df$weight)
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

I need to figure out how to do it because I need to loop over a list of 256 variables.

The results must be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(expss)

age: <br />

F <- df %>% filter(age >= 1 & age < 97)
fre(F$age, weight = F$weight)

 |  F$age | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |     15 |   100 |          13.3 |    13.3 |         13.3 |                    13.3 |
 |     20 |    80 |          10.7 |    10.7 |         10.7 |                    24.0 |
 |     25 |   300 |          40.0 |    40.0 |         40.0 |                    64.0 |
 |     39 |   100 |          13.3 |    13.3 |         13.3 |                    77.3 |
 |     40 |    20 |           2.7 |     2.7 |          2.7 |                    80.0 |
 |     48 |   100 |          13.3 |    13.3 |         13.3 |                    93.3 |
 |     65 |    50 |           6.7 |     6.7 |          6.7 |                   100.0 |
 | #Total |   750 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |   <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |

employment: <br />
F <- df %>% filter(employment >= 1 & employment < 97)
fre(F$employment, weight = F$weight)

 | F$employment | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |            1 |   750 |          71.4 |    71.4 |         71.4 |                    71.4 |
 |            2 |   300 |          28.6 |    28.6 |         28.6 |                   100.0 |
 |       #Total |  1050 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |         <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |

income: <br />
F <- df %>% filter(income >= 1 & income < 999997)
fre(F$income, weight = F$weight)

| F$income | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | -------- | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |     2500 |    20 |           3.2 |     3.2 |          3.2 |                     3.2 |
 |    10000 |   300 |          48.4 |    48.4 |         48.4 |                    51.6 |
 |    15000 |   250 |          40.3 |    40.3 |         40.3 |                    91.9 |
 |    65000 |    50 |           8.1 |     8.1 |          8.1 |                   100.0 |
 |   #Total |   620 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |     <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |
```

Comment: One  quick comment - a data frame is a list, where each list item is a column and must have the same length. Pulling columns from a data frame and putting them in a list isn't really doing anything... `list <- list(age = df$age, employment = df$employment, income = df$income)` is a long way to write `df[c("age", "employment", "income")]`, perhaps wrapped in `as.list()` if you really don't want it to be a data frame. To loop over a set of columns, it's often better to put the names only in a vector, e.g., `cols = c("age", "employment", "income")`, and then you can use `df[[i]]` in your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lapply` version.

```
library(dplyr)
library(expss)

vars_to_run <- c('age' , 'employment', 'income')
 
lapply(setNames(vars_to_run, vars_to_run), function(x){
  
  z <- sym(x)
  
  df_filter <- df %>%
    filter(!!z >= 1 & !!z <= max(!!z) - 2 ) 
  
  fre(df_filter[, x], weight = df_filter[, 'weight'])
  
  })
```

---

Or using base R and `[`.

```
lapply(setNames(vars_to_run, vars_to_run), function(x){
  
  df_filter <- df[df[x] >= 1 & df[x] <= max(df[x]) - 2, ]
  
  expss::fre(df_filter[x], weight = df_filter[ , 'weight'])
  
})
```

---

Both answers return a named list

```
$age
                                                                                            
 | df_filter[x] | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |           15 |   100 |           8.7 |     8.7 |          8.7 |                     8.7 |
 |           20 |    80 |           7.0 |     7.0 |          7.0 |                    15.7 |
 |           25 |   300 |          26.1 |    26.1 |         26.1 |                    41.7 |
 |           39 |   100 |           8.7 |     8.7 |          8.7 |                    50.4 |
 |           40 |    20 |           1.7 |     1.7 |          1.7 |                    52.2 |
 |           48 |   100 |           8.7 |     8.7 |          8.7 |                    60.9 |
 |           65 |    50 |           4.3 |     4.3 |          4.3 |                    65.2 |
 |           97 |   400 |          34.8 |    34.8 |         34.8 |                   100.0 |
 |       #Total |  1150 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |         <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |

$employment
                                                                                            
 | df_filter[x] | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |            1 |   750 |          71.4 |    71.4 |         71.4 |                    71.4 |
 |            2 |   300 |          28.6 |    28.6 |         28.6 |                   100.0 |
 |       #Total |  1050 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |         <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |

$income
                                                                                            
 | df_filter[x] | Count | Valid percent | Percent | Responses, % | Cumulative responses, % |
 | ------------ | ----- | ------------- | ------- | ------------ | ----------------------- |
 |         2500 |    20 |           2.0 |     2.0 |          2.0 |                     2.0 |
 |        10000 |   300 |          29.4 |    29.4 |         29.4 |                    31.4 |
 |        15000 |   250 |          24.5 |    24.5 |         24.5 |                    55.9 |
 |        65000 |    50 |           4.9 |     4.9 |          4.9 |                    60.8 |
 |       999997 |   400 |          39.2 |    39.2 |         39.2 |                   100.0 |
 |       #Total |  1020 |         100.0 |   100.0 |        100.0 |                         |
 |         <NA> |     0 |               |     0.0 |              |                         |
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see here. You'll need to update your `for` loop syntax. I added parentheses and converted the index to a number. You should also initialize the object you want the loop to fill up.

Next, you'll need to convert the columns to their names and filter using `rlang` syntax that converts `'age'` to `age` (standard evaluation to non-standard evaluation).

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df <- data.frame(sex = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2),
                 age = c(15, 40, 97, 25, 99, 65, 20, 99, 39, 48), 
                 nationality= c(1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 97, 2, 2, 2, 99),
                 employment = c(2, 1, 99, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 income = c(-1, 2500, 999997, 10000, 65000, 999998, 999999, 15000, -1, -1),
                 weight = c(100, 20, 400, 300, 50, 50, 80, 250, 100, 100))

## just list the names in a vector
loop_over <- c('age' ,'employment', 'income')

## initialize the object you want the loop to fill
final <- list()

for (i in 1:length(loop_over)) {
  ## !!sym() coverts the column name to non-standard evaluation
  temp <- df %>%
   filter( !!sym(loop_over[i]) >= 1 & !!sym(loop_over[i]) <= max(!!sym(loop_over[i])) - 2 )
  
  avg <-  fre( temp[[ loop_over[i] ]], weight = temp$weight )

  final[i] <- list(avg)
}
```